# asp.net script in task scheduler

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, cron, windows-server-2003

I got small asp.net script what could be executed as web page

http://localhost/myscript.aspx

and I need this script to be run every 30 seconds.

I am working on windows server 2003 with IIS 6.0
I got task scheduler available, however launching 
iexplorer.exe http://localhost/myscript.aspx open browser even putting JavaScript windows.close () inside page, so in a few min I will have too many browsers open

how to run it similar to Unix Lynx http://localhost/myscript.aspx > null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [PowerShell](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968930) then you can create a task that runs the following command:

```
powershell.exe -c (new-object system.net.webclient).downloadstring('http://localhost/myscript.aspx')
```

Comment: I can not install anything so PowerShell is not a solution, I can only use task scheduler to run this page - question is how

Comment: It is a web host or something? It doesn't really matter where PowerShell is installed, as long as it can make a request to the web server. The bottom line is you need to be able to install *something* somewhere because as far as I know, there is no built-in command line utility for making HTTP requests in Windows 2003.

Comment: @bensiu: PowerShell may already be installed. Also, WScript may already be installed - you can write a JavaScript (or VBScript) file and have it executed via Task Manager. See http://www.asp101.com/articles/john/schedule/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

I would instead start a background thread in the Application_Start event and then use a timer object to trigger the action every 30 Seconds in this background thread.

Comment: You still gotta have something requesting the page in order to start up the worker process. Plus it's not really a good idea to create background threads in ASP.NET applications which limits your options for scaling out.

Comment: No,since I start the thread in Application_Start event and from there on the thread is on its own. All I need is a trigger for the Application_Start event.

Comment: IIS can and will kill your worker process for a variety of reasons including but not limited to idle time, memory use, slow response times, etc. You can't be sure the application is even running unless it's handling a request.

Comment: Agreed with IIS killing the process for memory use etc. However for things like this I would rather create a background service like Windows Service unless there is a dire need to tag it with the ASP.Net Worker process and am not sure what is the requirement of the OP in that context. Also if IIS kills the process then the web app is no killed too in which case I don't think the background process is needed till its restarted

Answer (score -1):

save your vbs file,

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "iexplore your url", 9

WScript.Sleep 20000 ' Give ie some time to load

'Close the browser

WshShell.SendKeys "%F"

WshShell.SendKeys "C"