# Windows Task Scheduler to execute .aspx page using Powershell

Tags: asp.net, windows, powershell, html, execute

I want to use Windows Task Scheduler to execute my ASP.NET web page (.aspx). I read that Windows Powershell can help in this. The post [asp.net script in task scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559978/asp-net-script-in-task-scheduler)

tells a command "powershell.exe -c (new-object system.net.webclient).downloadstring('http://localhost/myscript.aspx')"
to execute .aspx page. But I'm unable to add this line into Windows Task Scheduler, (I'm using Windows XP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the run field of the scheduled task:

`powershell.exe -command "(new-object system.net.webclient).downloadstring('http://localhost/myscript.aspx')"`.

That's it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Andy, but which version of Windows are you using?

Comment: @hotcoder That's a screenshot from XP. Open your scheduled tasks window and right-click and select New. Don't use the wizard.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a powershell file like task.ps1 with the command you have shown and schedule execution of this ps1 file.

Such file should not contain powershell.exe command.